# Tesseract-OCR y Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tesseract

Tengo un programa bastante simple donde estoy practicando con Tesseract-OCR dentro de python donde estoy viendo su funcionalidad para ver imágenes

```js
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import time
import os

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

try:
    print("Abriendo imagen...")
    image = Image.open('imagenes/testocr.png')
    print("Realizando OCR...")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    print("Texto detectado:")
    print(text)
except Exception as e:
    time.sleep(10)
    print(f"Error al utilizar Tesseract-OCR: {e}")
```

el codigo de hecho funciona perfectamente.

El problema realmente se ubica al momento de pasar este codigo a un ejecutable hecho por "Pyinstaller" el cual al ejecutar este directamente no me funciona, de hecho el programa llega hasta el primer print (print("Abriendo imagen...") despues de ahi me salta el error

> Error al utilizar Tesseract-OCR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\...\imagenes\testocr.png'

Este es el comando que uso para convertirlo en ejecutable con Pyinstaller

> pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe;Tesseract-OCR" --add-binary "imagenes/testocr.png;." --hidden-import="PIL" prueba_tesseract.py

No entiendo de donde viene el problema incluso sabiendo que en visual studio code funciona bien. Agradeceria cualquier ayuda

Respondo cualquier duda para ayudarme a resolver el problema